# Android desktop: How to suppress the new message counter bubble on launcher icons?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

Specifically on Whatsapp and Messages....

I want to completely suppress the message counter. For it to never, ever, appear.

I have played with a number of options, restarted, and can't seem to nail it.

Android 12 on a Sony Xperia phone.

Answer (score 1):

They are called app icon badges.

If you are on Android 12 there must be an option in `Settings > Notifications > Advanced Options > App icon badges toggle`

Also if you `long press the app icon > app info > notifications > App ion badges`

That's that but I'm not sure about Sony Xperia specifically but as Firelord said and from [this thread](https://community.sony.co.uk/t5/z-series/notification-badge-counter/td-p/3278360), I am inferring that you will need to change the launcher. 
Personal suggestion: use [Square Home](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.squarehome2&hl=en&gl=US)

Comment: In Notifications, I do not have "Advanced" and cannot find any references to "App icon badges"

I have something called "Notification dots" which I just turned off globally.

Thanks for the reference to Square Home -- that looks really great! (though not going there just now)